# Solving Lx = b for big sparse Laplacian matrices

Tags: linear-solver, sparse-matrix, libraries

What algorithm is more practically suited in terms of performance for solving the $\mathbf{Lx=b}$ equation, where $\mathbf{L}$ is a generic Laplacian matrix (associated to a strongly connected graph, its first eigenvalue being null in most cases). $\mathbf{L}$ can have more than 1 million rows and less than 15 non-null entries per row.

In my specific case, I tried using C++ with the Eigen library for a small example. Seeing that most numerical solver libraries tend to offer both conjugate gradient and Cholesky methods, I still need a more educated advice regarding the pros and cons of such sparse solvers. As far as my experience goes, CG should be better, but I suspect the sheer size of the problem can be overwhelming in the end.

Comment: I would be careful with the statement that $L$ is definitely SPD, since a graph Laplacian has a nullspace of size of the number of connected components. Similarly, a finite discretization of the Laplacian operator can also have a nullspace.

Comment: I agree.. I'll edit the question to be more specific.

Comment: Algebraic multigrid might be something to look into

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Which one was faster when you tried using Eigen? You may also consider [Trilinos](http://trilinos.org/) if you're using C++.

By "generic Laplacian matrix", do you mean a finite difference / finite element discretization of the Laplace operator on some domain, or do you mean the Laplacian of some graph $G$?

Whether or not your solver is overwhelmed as you scale up the number of unknowns depends strongly on the underlying matrix. For example, if $L$ were a band matrix, then direct solution methods like Cholesky require no more space than the original matrix takes up to begin with. On the other hand, if the matrix has a less regular structure -- e.g. it comes from a 5-point stencil in 2D or a random graph -- then matrix factorizations will have a lot of fill-in and CG becomes preferable. In my own experience, the latter case is more common. Generally speaking, for a PDE in 2 dimensions or more, direct methods are faster for problems with less than ~25,000 unknowns, after which iterative methods are the clear winner.

In either case, there's a lot to gain by [permuting the matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuthill%E2%80%93McKee_algorithm) so that its bandwidth is reduced. For direct solution methods, this reduces the amount of fill-in; for iterative solution methods, it can enhance locality of reference when accessing the elements of $x$.

Finally, for iterative methods, choosing a good preconditioner is as important, if not more so, than choosing a good solver. Both Trilinos and [PETSc](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/) have implementations of multigrid preconditioners, for which your problem is the textbook application.

Comment: Thanks for the nice pointers. I'm indeed considering graph Laplacians (planar but irregular strongly connected graphs).

Comment: I've tried to benchmark LDLT vs CG in Eigen (since I already had an application that used this library) and LDLT crashed at runtime even for a very simple 3x3 matrix that was positive definite. To make sure it was doable, I ran a Cholesky decomposition using SciLab and it worked like a charm. Maybe I'm using a version of Eigen (from 2013) that has a horrendous bug..

Answer (score 9):

Daniel Shapero's answer is excellent, but I felt I should add the following:

Properly preconditioned iterative methods will almost certainly win here, unless your systems have a very, very special structure.

There's a considerable recent literature, unfortunately mostly of the "asymptotic a priori bounds on running time" variety, on solvers for graph Laplacian systems.  See [Dan Spielman's page](http://www.cs.yale.edu/homes/spielman/precon/precon.html) for references to papers.

Spielman's page suggests using the algebraic multigrid method, in particular [Oren Livne and Achi Brandt's LAMG](http://code.google.com/p/lamg/) to solve Laplacian systems in practice.  Since it's already implemented and many of the recent Laplacian solvers that come with provable running time bounds aren't, I'd suggest giving it a shot.

Comment: Very helpful information. Although I cannot accept two answers, your also deserves it.

Comment: @teodron: No, you accepted the right answer.  Maybe after a few more years of development in the field something like this one will be the right one to accept.  But we're not there yet.

Comment: What about HSC - http://www.cs.huji.ac.il/~raananf/projects/hsc/?

Comment: @Drazick: I haven't used it.  Give it a shot on whichever problems you're interested in.

Comment: I just thought it would be great of you added it to your answer. As you seemed to create a list.

Comment: @Drazick: Wasn't my intent.  "List questions" and "list answers" are generally discouraged on StackExchange sites---they tend to grow without bound and people sometimes get upset when their stuff isn't included.  I just meant to point out another approach that's currently theoretical but holds some promise for the future.